# Working with AngularJS $locationProvider in MVC5

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, angularjs-routing

I am trying to change the URL of the page if an $html callback is a success.

**Module:**

```
var app = angular.module('mymodule', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider.
    when('/Home/Index', {
        templateUrl: '/Home/Index',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/User/InsertInitialUserInfo',
        data: insertUserParams
    }).success(function (data, status) {
        $location.url("/Home/Index");
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        console.log(status);
    });
```

**MVC Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

After my controller code runs the URL changes from : localhost:xxxx/Home/Register to localhost:xxxx/Home/Index

But the view doesn't change. What am I missing?

Comment: did you try using `$location.path("/Home/Index")`

Comment: Try $location.url("Home/Index");
And you have of course an ng-view declaration in your view.

Comment: $location.path didn't work too.

@Edminsson, you got it. I was missing ng-view declaration.

Comment: Could you post it as an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only missing one important component, the ng-view declaration in your view

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

This is placeholder for the templates you specify in the app.config.